# Using SQLAlchemy ORM for a non-primary key, unique, auto-incrementing id

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I run the following code, I am expecting the first_name, and last_name to be a composite primary key and for the id to be an autoincrementing index for the row, but not to act as the primary key, as there the information in the rest of the table is what I need to define it's uniqueness, rather than the given ID.

```
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "people"
    id = Column(Integer, index=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True, primary_key=False)
    first_name = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    last_name = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(db)
    session.add_all([
        Person(first_name="Winston", last_name="Moy"),
        Person(first_name="Bill", last_name="Gates"),
        Person(first_name="Steve", last_name="Jobs"),
        Person(first_name="Quinten", last_name="Coldwater")
    ])
    session.commit()
```

The problem I view the results in DataGrip, I'm getting the following table. The data is not in the order added, and the id column is null, instead of the auto-incrementing integer I'm expecting it to be.
[image: Image of person table]

To be clear: My question is: How would I make an auto-incrementing index for a SQLAlchemy ORM class that is not a primary key?

Comment: If you don't *need* incrementing, you can use UUID4s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of writing this, SQLAlchemy 1.1 does not support auto-incrementing on a non-primary key field.

Answer (score 3):

### Postgresql 2022 answer:

the following code

```
import uuid
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, String, Sequence
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID

class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Test'

    id_sec = Sequence(__tablename__ + "_id_seq")
    id = Column(Integer, id_sec, server_default=id_sec.next_value(), nullable=False)
    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)

    # your data
    ....
```

generates the following table:

```
                                      Table "public.Test"
    Column     |       Type        | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                    
---------------+-------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------------
 id            | integer           |           | not null | nextval('"Test_id_seq"'::regclass)
 uuid          | uuid              |           | not null |
```

so you can insert rows without specifying the `id`

```
PostgreSQL 13.5
SQLAlchemy==1.4.29
```

Answer (score 3):

### SQLAlchemy 1.4 and above

In addition to sequences, you can use `sqlalchemy.schema.Identity` with some supported databases. OP's example becomes:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Identity
...

Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = "people"
    id = Column(Integer, Identity(), index=True, unique=True)
    first_name = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    last_name = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(db)
    session.add_all([
        Person(first_name="Winston", last_name="Moy"),
        Person(first_name="Bill", last_name="Gates"),
        Person(first_name="Steve", last_name="Jobs"),
        Person(first_name="Quinten", last_name="Coldwater")
    ])
    session.commit()
```

As of writing, the Identity construct is currently known to be supported by:

- PostgreSQL as of version 10.
- Oracle as of version 12. It also supports passing `always=None` to enable the default generated mode and the parameter `on_null=True` to specify “ON NULL” in conjunction with a “BY DEFAULT” identity column.
- Microsoft SQL Server. MSSQL uses a custom syntax that only supports the start and increment parameters, and ignores all other.

For more info on arguments and supported databases, see the following

- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Identity
- https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#identity-ddl

Answer (score 1):

### a workaroud here for mysql:

After sqlalchemy create table,
　alter table manully (add AUTO_INCREMENT property) use DDL.
　( at table `after_create` event ).

then it will execute **on demand** like `create_all()`

### test code (1.4.x):

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

# --- 1. define table
base = declarative_base()
class store(base):
    __tablename__ = 'store'
    id  = Column(Integer,    autoincrement=True, unique=True, primary_key=False) # AI here not work

    did = Column(String(64), unique=False, nullable=False)
    fid = Column(String(64), unique=False, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('did', 'fid', name='idx_did_fid'),
    )


print(store)

# --- 2. fix autoincre on non-primary key // will execute as need, like create_all() dose
from sqlalchemy import event, DDL
event.listen(
    base.metadata, 'after_create',  DDL('ALTER TABLE `store` CHANGE `id` `id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT')
)

# --- 3. create table as need
base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```