# Auto increment non primary column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

In my db model I need `userId` and `forumPostId` to be a composite primary key. But I need `id` to be a auto incremented value. But when I'm trying to insert new row in table getting `none` in id instead of a auto incremented integer.

```py
class ForumPostFollow(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "forum_post_follow"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,autoincrement=True,nullable=False,unique=True)
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'),primary_key=True)
    forumPostId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('forum_post.id'),primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False)
```

My package versions

> Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2 SQLAlchemy>=1.3.0

This question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530854/using-sqlalchemy-orm-for-a-non-primary-key-unique-auto-incrementing-id). But it's for version 1.1

**Updated Question**

I've changed my `id` columns sequence from terminal

```sql
ALTER TABLE forum_post_follow DROP COLUMN id;
ALTER TABLE forum_post_follow ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;
```

Then my altered columns looks like this

[image]

But still getting same error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, 1, t, null).

[SQL: INSERT INTO forum_post_follow (id, "userId", "forumPostId", active) VALUES (%(id)s, %(userId)s, %(forumPostId)s, %(active)s)]
[parameters: {'id': None, 'userId': 1, 'forumPostId': 1, 'active': True}]
```

Comment: See here [autoincrement](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html?highlight=autoincrement#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement). Basically it won't work unless column is part of a `primary key` or you have set up the field as `serial/IDENTITY` manually on the server.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver can you please have a look in my updated question

Comment: `'id': None` means you are trying to pass `NULL` into the `id` column.  That trips the `NOT NULL` constraint. Leave the `id` field out of the `INSERT` and Postgres will automatically add the value.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have the same problem as the author of this question. Had the same idea as you. But how do I leave out the id field? I tried this "del db_obj['id']" before using session.add(db_obj). Unfortunately this gives me the following error: "'Job' object does not support item deletion"

Comment: @Jabb that is going to need its own question as you will need to supply more information about your model, query, table schema, SQLAlchemy version, etc.

Comment: have you found a workaround solution on this? I encountered the same issue with you. I can alter the table in DB manually, but the main question is how to bypass sqlalchemy not null checker

Answer (score 1):

Extending @JellyBeans answer, For SQLAlchemy version 1.4, you can do something like this.
Just take care that you don't insert value in `non_pkey` column so that postgres picks default value which is auto incrementing.

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, Integer, VARCHAR, Column, Sequence, func, MetaData

metadata = MetaData()

seq_non_pkey_auto_inc = Sequence('non_pkey_auto_inc_seq', metadata=metadata)
n_tbl_test = 'tbl_test'
s_tbl_entity = Table(
    n_tbl_test, metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column('non_pkey', Integer, nullable=False, server_default=func.nextval('non_pkey_auto_inc_seq')),
    Column('col1', VARCHAR(100), nullable=False),
    Column('col2', VARCHAR(50), nullable=False)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for psql - I created the table, then added the serial column manually. If you set the default value to the nextval() function and refer to the sequence ({schema}.{table}_{col-name}_seq), then it will explicitly call for the next value on insert as opposed to that happening behind the scenes, which gets it working. Not ideal, but far from terrible

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.autoincrement ADD COLUMN non_pkey_auto_inc SERIAL;
```

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

db = SQLAlchemy()

class MyTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "autoincrement"
    __table_args__ = "public"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    non_pkey_auto_inc = db.Column(db.Integer(), default=func.nextval(f"{__table_args__['schema']}.{__tablename__}_non_pkey_auto_inc_seq"))
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and found that as per [SQLAlchemy 1.3 Documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html):

> For the case where this default generation of `IDENTITY` is not desired, specify `False` for the `Column.autoincrement` flag, on the first integer primary key column:

so you might want to try this:

```py
class ForumPostFollow(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "forum_post_follow"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,autoincrement=False,primary_key=True,nullable=False,unique=True)
    userId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('user.id'),primary_key=True)
    forumPostId = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey('forum_post.id'),primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean,nullable=False)
```

Comment: Isn't one table supposed to have only one primary_key?

Comment: @ZainQasmi multiple primary_keys will create a composite key.