# Creating an autoincrement column via sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, auto-increment

I am using a Postgresql database via sqlalchemy orm. The table is really basic:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column

class Network(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(60))
    type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(60))
    version: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer)
```

I would like to convert the `version` column into something which check if same `name` & same `type` row exists. If yes, then increase the previous `version` with 1.

So imagine my table already has following rows:

```
id    name    type    version
0     foo     big     1
1     bar     big     1
```

And I insert one more `(foo, big)` into the table then it should be automaticly:

```
id    name    type    version
0     foo     big     1
1     bar     big     1
2     foo     big     2
```

Is something like this possible? BTW, it should get also default version 1 if same `name` & same `type` does not exists.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76346178/5320906) answer your question?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I made the answer you mention work, however, it saves a value as sequence inside the database for each entry inside the networks table. So it is like a primary key auto-increament. What I need is though only increase if already same name&type network exists inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

use `before_insert` event:

```
class Network(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'networks'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(60))
    type: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(sa.String(60))
    version: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(sa.Integer)


def update_version(mapper, connection, target):
    session = Session.object_session(target)

    # Check if a row with the same name and type already exists
    existing_row = session.query(Network.version) \
        .filter(Network.name == target.name) \
        .filter(Network.type==target.type) \
        .order_by(Network.version.desc()) \
        .first()

    if existing_row:
        # If it exists, increase the version by 1
        target.version = existing_row.version + 1
    else:
        # If it doesn't exist, set the version to 1
        target.version = 1


event.listen(Network, 'before_insert', update_version)
```